# Static dependency injection factory, right or wrong?

Tags: c#, architecture, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I very recently have hit a brick wall when I gave a shot at Ninject in the project I'm working  on.

I have went through all kind of questions, systematically requestionning my design and architecture in favour of dependency injection.

1. [Is this right to inject the container/kernel to the main application presenter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753750/is-this-right-to-inject-the-container-kernel-to-the-main-application-presenter)
2. [How to configure Ninject to use along with NHibernate in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775724/how-to-configure-ninject-to-use-along-with-nhibernate-in-winforms)
3. [Conditional dependency injection binding only when property not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793037/conditional-dependency-injection-binding-only-when-property-not-null)
4. [What did I get wrong, DI or Design, and how should I go about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800265/what-did-i-get-wrong-di-or-design-and-how-should-i-go-about-it)

After hours, and hours, and hours of searching, I came across that article from Justin Etheredge who speaks of his static DIFactory class.

- [Creating a binding factory for Ninject](http://www.codethinked.com/creating-a-binding-factory-for-ninject)

I now wonder, is it not making things work like magic using a static DI factory?

I'd like to hear pros and cons of using a static DI factory in a real-world application.

Also, are IoC and DI the same, or are they very similar, though some differences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [static DI Factory is a Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryorServiceLocator), and a [Service Locator is an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern) because it will make it **difficult to reason about your code**:

- It breaks encapsulation.
- It violates the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).
- It makes it more difficult to spot violations of the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
- It makes object composition more difficult, because it hides the composition context from the Service Locator.
- It breaks the [Hollywood Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle).

The only advantage of Service Locator is that it's *slightly* [easier to understand than Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16176517/126014). However, DI isn't that hard to grasp [once you get over a few conceptual hurdles](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Succeeding-Dependency-Injection).

The relationship between IoC and DI is that [DI is a special case of IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3227404/126014).

Comment: What if certain types cannot be instantiated on application startup, because they need user credentials to instantiate correctly? For instance, the `NHibernante.ISessionFactory` is such problem as it can't be instantiated without a proper connection string, and once created, it won't let one change its connection string. As a workaround, one can supply an `IDbConnection`, and loses the second level cache which holds traces of an object throughout the `ISession` lifecycle. Then one would need the user to provide his credentials, and now the `ISessionFactory` dependency is no longer a problem.

Comment: Would it be an `AbstractFactory` which would allow new types to be registered? How would you go about it?

Comment: If you can't resolve a sub-graph at run-time, you can always add another layer of indirection. An Abstract Factory would be one option. Here's more information about [implementing an Abstract Factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory).