# How to inject multiple presenters into the main presenter?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, mvp

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759294/2669681), I could inject the dependencies to the constructor.   However, what if let's say I have 10 'sub-presenters'? Should I inject all those via the constructor?  What's the recommended design pattern (factory method, facade, etc) to use for this situation?  I appreciate if you can you give sample code to test it using using NUnit and NSubstitute?  Thanks in advance!

```
public void PresenterMain(IViewMain view
, IServiceMain service
, IAddNewJobPresenter addNewJobPresenter
, IClientManagementPresenter clientManagementPresenter
, IJobBatchesPresenter jobBatchesPresenter
, IReportsPresenter reportPresenter...etc)
```

Comment: If your `IPresenter` objects are composed at compile time then pass them via `Constructor injection`, you should strive for `Constructor injection` where possible.  You could provide your constructor with an `IEnumerable<T> where T : IPresenter` either via your IoC container, or poor mans DI if you're not using one.

Answer (score 1):

Given your consumer needs to use 10 instances of presenter, there are a couple options. Here is some basic framework to setup the scenario:

```
public interface IPresenter
{
    void Present();
}

public interface IConsumer
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class SomeConsumer : IConsumer
{
    private readonly IPresenter presenter;

    public SomeConsumer(IPresenter presenter)
    {
        if (presenter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("presenter");
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.presenter.Present();
    }
}
```

You could use the [composite pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite), in which you could then order the presenters in a list.

```
public class Presenter1 : IPresenter
{
    public void Present()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}

public class Presenter2 : IPresenter
{
    public void Present()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}

public class Presenter3 : IPresenter
{
    public void Present()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}

public class CompositePresenter : IPresenter
{
    private readonly IPresenter[] presenters;

    public CompositePresenter(IPresenter[] presenters)
    {
        if (presenters == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("presenters");
        this.presenters = presenters;
    }

    public void Present()
    {
        // Do nothing except delegate the call to the nested
        // instances. You may need to do some extra work to deal
        // with multiple return values, like add up the values
        // or decide which value works best for the scenario.
        foreach (var presenter in this.presenters)
        {
            presenter.Present();
        }
    }
}
```

And then wire it up like:

```
var presenter1 = new Presenter1();
var presenter2 = new Presenter2();
var presenter3 = new Presenter3();
var compositePresenter = new CompositePresenter(new IPresenter[] {
    presenter1,
    presenter2,
    presenter3
});

var consumer = new SomeConsumer(compositePresenter);
```

Or you could use a [decorator pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator):

```
public class Presenter1 : IPresenter
{
    public Presenter1(IPresenter innerPresenter)
    {
        if (innerPresenter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("innerPresenter");
        this.innerPresenter = innerPresenter;
    }

    public void Present()
    {
        // Do something here

        // You could make this call conditional
        this.innerPresenter.Present();

        // Or do something here
    }
}

public class Presenter2 : IPresenter
{
    public Presenter2(IPresenter innerPresenter)
    {
        if (innerPresenter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("innerPresenter");
        this.innerPresenter = innerPresenter;
    }

    public void Present()
    {
        // Do something here

        // You could make this call conditional
        this.innerPresenter.Present();

        // Or do something here
    }
}

public class Presenter3 : IPresenter
{
    public Presenter3(IPresenter innerPresenter)
    {
        if (innerPresenter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("innerPresenter");
        this.innerPresenter = innerPresenter;
    }

    public void Present()
    {
        // Do something here

        // You could make this call conditional
        this.innerPresenter.Present();

        // Or do something here
    }
}

public class NullPresenter : IPresenter
{
    public void Present()
    {
        // Do nothing here - this class is a placeholder
        // in case you want to expand the design later
    }
}
```

And then wire it up like:

```
var nullPresenter = new NullPresenter();
var presenter3 = new Presenter3(nullPresenter);
var presenter2 = new Presenter2(presenter3);
var presenter1 = new Presenter1(presenter2);

var consumer = new SomeConsumer(presenter1);
```